# When execute commands with cf, it gives “No org and space targeted”

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, paas

When execute commands with cf, it gives “No org and space targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG -s SPACE' to target an org and space”[image]

Comment: Can you list your orgs with `cf orgs`?

Comment: what does `cf api` give you?

Answer (score 1):

Following http://basics-workshop.cloudfoundry.org/agenda/, ran into the same problem. I had created my user, but not completed the trial account setup.
You can name and create your org as a step to sign up for a trial account. The user Pivotal creates for you does not have the privileges to create an org from the CLI. After the org has been created, you can create your space from the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly root cause is pointed wrong API endpoint as an example your URi may not be pointing to correct region of your service. Find Ref;
[CouldFoundry CLI](https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/public/index.html#ov_intro_reg)

If you narrow downed and your are confident that connected to API then try with creating organization with below.

```
cf create-org ORGNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of possibilities.

It could be that your login token has expired. Try doing `cf login -a <url>` again.

If you continue to get no orgs and spaces targeted, it could be that the user account may not have privileges for any of the orgs. Make sure that the org and space roles have been set for the account you are using to log in.

Answer (score 0):

which cloud foundry service provider you are subscribed to? if it is pivotal, please access https://login.run.pivotal.io/ and click the red arrow below:
[click the 'Pivotal Web Service'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYqib.png) to create organization and space manually, later you can bind it in `cf cli` via `cf target -o ORG -s SPACE`.